# I get HttpErrorResponse error when logging in on angular 11. Status 200

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

[image]

I am getting an error like this. Couldn't find the solution.

[image]

```
  login(signInRequestPayload: SignInRequestPayload): Observable<boolean> {
return this.httpClient.post<SignInResponse>( '/api/v1/registration/login', signInRequestPayload)
  .pipe(map(data => {
    this.localStorage.store('token', data.token);
    return true;
  }));
```

}

Comment: Please paste your error messages/code/JSON as text. It appears that your api is returning something which can't be mapped to a `SignInResponse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be receiving text as the response type, but by default Angular expects JSON. Try setting `{responseType: 'text'}` in the `options` of the call